# Liquid syntax error for 'gist' tag with github-pages gem for Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

I have a Jekyll site that is hosted on Github Pages. I am trying to get my site to render locally before I push to Github, but I get the following error when running `bundle exec jekyll serve --safe`:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 13): Unknown tag 'gist'
```

My `_config.yml` contains the following (among other things):

```
gems:
  - jekyll-gist
```

My `Gemfile` is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

And `bundle show jekyll-gist` shows a path to the gem that is installed.

I'm stumped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--safe` argument means "Disable custom plugins, and ignore symbolic links", which means it will ignore the `jekyll-gist` gem.

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

You can get around this by amending your `_config.yml` to match what Github will use when rendering your site on their servers.

```
github: [metadata]
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
gems:
  - jekyll-coffeescript
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-mentions
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-redirect-from
whitelist:
  - jekyll-coffeescript
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-mentions
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

I have pieced this together from a few different sources. Too bad they don't explicitly tell you to do this.